# Finding Max aggregate of list of Tuples

Tags: python-3.x

Write a Python function maxaggregate(l) that takes a list of pairs of the form (name,score) as argument, where name is a string and score is an integer. Each pair is to be interpreted as the score of the named player. For instance, an input of the form [('Kohli',73),('Ashwin',33),('Kohli',7),('Pujara',122),('Ashwin',90)] represents two scores of 73 and 7 for Kohli, two scores of 33 and 90 for Ashwin and one score of 122 for Pujara. Your function should compute the players who have the highest aggregate score (aggegrate = total, so add up all scores for that name) and return the list of names of these players as a list, sorted in alphabetical order. If there is a single player, the list will contain a single name.

For instance:

```
maxaggregate([('Kohli',73),('Ashwin',33),('Kohli',7),('Pujara',122),('Ashwin',90)])
```

should return:

```
['Ashwin']
```

because the aggregate score of Kolhi is 80, of Ashwin is 123 and of Pujara is 122, of which 123 is the highest.

```
def maxaggregate(l):
  d = {}
  for i in l:
    if i[0] in d:
      d[i[0]] += i[1]
    else:
      d[i[0]] = i[1]
  m = max(list(d.values()))
  x = []
  for i in d:
    if d[i] == m:
      x.append(i)
  return sorted(x)
```

Comment: It's a easy task but before giving you the answer, I wanted to give you hint. Try to iterate through list and make dictionary which has unique keys to save/add/update the score of each player.
At the end you have the dictionary with player name and score without duplication.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def maxaggregate(lst):
    # If a key is not in the dict it will
    # default the value for that key to 0 (the default int).
    d = defaultdict(int)

    # Sum up the scores
    for name, score in lst:
        d[name] += score

    # Return the max score by iterating
    # over the defaultdict's items and finding
    # the max score (the 2nd element 
    #     in the item is the score thus the x[1]).
    return max(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

r = maxaggregate([('Kohli',73),('Ashwin',33),('Kohli',7),('Pujara',122),('Ashwin',90)]) 
print(r) # ('Ashwin', 123)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the list, create a dict to keep the scores and add up the scores by name. Then keeping note of the highest score you find with the associated name.

```
def maxaggregate(scores):
  agg_results = {}
  max_name = None
  max_val = None
  for name, score in scores:
    score += agg_results.get(name, 0)       # Add up the score
    agg_results[name] = score               # Save it in the dict
    if max_val is None or max_val < score:  # Compare scores
      max_val = score
      max_name = name
  return name

print(maxaggregate([('Kohli',73),('Ashwin',33),('Kohli',7),('Pujara',122),('Ashwin',90)]))
```

Returns: `Ashwin`

This solution only iterates over the list once.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I upvoted yours, nice solution with `defaultdict`, I always forget its existence haha. About your comment, by doing `not max_val` it wouldn't consider an score `0` and there is no restriction about this. What if we have `[("Carl", 0)]` as input, it should return `Carl`.

Comment: Yeah I realized that and deleted my comment but you noticed to quick. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, using a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile

def maxaggregate(l):
    c = Counter()
    for k, v in l:
        c[k] += v
    mc = c.most_common()
    max_count = mc[0][1]
    return sorted(name for name, _ in takewhile(lambda i: i[1] == max_count, mc))
```